# Developer story erased all of my job descriptions/responsibilities

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I just noticed the `!` icon reappear in the Developer Story tab in my profile, indicating that my Developer Story was incomplete. Clicking through, the orange box in the sidebar (nice addition) told me:

> At least one complete with a minimum of 2 technologies and 150 char. for responsibilities

This confused me, because I was sure that at least one of my job listings had a long description. But scrolling down, I saw that all of my job descriptions were missing. When I went to edit a job, the "Responsibilities" text box was entirely empty.

I'm quite sure I didn't erase these myself. In fact, I've made some small changes since importing from the existing Careers system, which I guess I've now lost..?

Comment: Looking into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting!

We recently changed how item descriptions and readings are rendered and stored (making it more similar to posts). The initial designs only envisioned markdown mini support, support for full markdown was tacked on later. The code that moved the data around had a bug and item descriptions were not moved correctly. I just ran another migration that restored your old descriptions from history.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing happen to my account as well.  Perhaps this is a bit more systematic?

Comment: @Makoto your case is a bit different. You didn't change your items' descriptions after importing (and we didn't record history for imports, adding it to our todo list), there was nothing to restore your descriptions from. You can re-import from careers to get the old descriptions back

Comment: I have even [worse](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336461/my-cv-is-completely-lost-after-developer-story-release) issue