# My CV is completely lost after Developer Story release

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, cv-import

I have my CV completely erased after SO introduced Developer story. It was stored under the link https://stackoverflow.com/cv/astashonak and there was **plenty** of information (now I renewed only the last workplace).

I found out that **ALL** the info I entered is missing. Completely all:

- books
- jobs/responsibilities
- educations
- courses
- my questions
  and so on...

It is big effort to enter all this stuff again. It's awful and frustrating.

What happened to all of my information? Can it be restored?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Our dev team has looked into this and it appears that a miscommunication resulted in the disappearance of your data.  On October 3rd you submitted a request asking that your account be deleted from Careers.  The request specifically said:

> As far as I understand, careers.stackoverflow.com is a site for employers. If so, then you mistakenly created page there. I already have candidate page on SO, so could you please remove my account on careers.stackoverflow.com.

As a result, the support team deleted your CV.  Based on your email and the post here, it appears there was a bit of confusion about the purpose of your Careers CV.  Careers was not a site used exclusively by employers, users were able to search for and apply for jobs with the CV on the site. However, that wasn't clear  when you requested your CV to be deleted, our team followed your request and deleted the CV.

Our developers are actively working to see if they can pull you previous CV from a database backup.  We apologize for the deletion of your CV and we're working on fixing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I wasn't aware that careers.stackoverflow.com and Jobs on SO are interconnected. Maybe there are too many services which features overlap each other.

Comment: @Suncatcher We were able to restore your CV from an old Careers backup.  If you go to [your story](http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/911419), you should see an option on the right side that will allow you to re-import your data. Can you try that to see if it restores your data?

Comment: many thanks to you! I am very pleased you were able to do it.

Comment: probably I was confused by the [answer of your colleague](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314531/911419), that Careers is a purely employer resource.